# How to change the anchor point of a vector asset?

Tags: android, vector-graphics

I have been trying to change the anchor position of a vector asset (similar to the google map marker capability). However, it turns out it is not an easy task to do. By default, the setX() command uses the top left corner of the canvas, on which the vector asset is defined, to place the image view populated by the corresponding vector asset. However, I want the setX() and setY() command to use the center of the image view for any placement procedure. Is there any way that I can accomplish this?

The below picture might help:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use Inkscape and convert a png or jpg to svg very easy .
download it from this [link](https://inkscape.org/en/release/0.92.3/)

in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD29KTVHht4) video you can see how it work

then use this [link](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) to convert your file to vector

hope it work.

Comment: I have already had the vector asset and do not need to create one. I want to change the anchore point of the asset with which the image is placed on my application. Any vector asset, whether it is extracted from jpg file or called from the Android studio vector asset library, has a canvas on which the icon will be drawn. I need to change the corresponding anchor point.

Comment: @MahmoudH Ok.you want to edit anchor? in this program you can create any vector with desired anchor.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this application a try, but there should be an easier way to place vector-based icons on the screen. Otherwise, I have to create every icon that I want to place on the screen from the scratch, although they are already available in the android studio.